# Google oAuth api to retrieve contacts issue with permissions

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

When passing Api request to this URL
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

A screen comes requesting this permissions. Is there any URL that just only asks user to "retrieve you contacts" instead of managing it.

SHOPBOX.IO is requesting permission to:

```
Manage your contacts
Perform these operations when I'm not using the application
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions the user is asked for at the authorization screen is dependent on the scope that you specify. Of course for accessing different endpoints you have to request certain scopes.

For accessing the [Google's Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20) this scope is required:

> *https://www.google.com/m8/feeds* - read/write access to Contacts and Contact Groups

As this is your only option and there is no read-only scope available, the user gets warned that you *could* edit his contacts, even if you won't do that.